# Finding system of equations such that

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

The question is:

In $\mathbb{R}^4$  plane $V$ is given, $V=\mathrm{span}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ where $\alpha_1=[1,3,4,1]$, $\alpha_2=[1,2,2,3] $

a) Find the formula for isomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$, such that $\varphi(V)=\mathrm{span}(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$

b) Find the system of equations which will describe $V$.

I know how to solve a) but have problems with solving b) I am looking for straightforward solutions. (i've posted subpoint a) because I think it is somehow related to b))

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

You intuition is right, because $\varphi(V)$  is the orthogonal complement to $\mathrm{span}(\epsilon_3,\epsilon_4)$. So the required system is

$\cases{
(\varphi(v), \epsilon_3)=0\\ 
(\varphi(v), \epsilon_4)=0 
}$